# I'm trying to figure out some assembly language code generated by the Visual Studio compiler

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to figure out some assembly code generated by the debug build of an old C++ project that I've taken over. Windows-10 Visual Studio 2019.

I have a method call that looks like this:

```
P2PRespMsg::P2PRespMsg(int port, const char * address, L3Obj* rcv_pro, 
                       fn_process fnprocess)
                      : NEDSMsg(port, address, rcv_pro, fnprocess)
```

This is the assembly code generated

```
00007FF68DE89ACB  lea         rax,[rsp+30h]  
00007FF68DE89AD0  mov         rdi,rax  
00007FF68DE89AD3  mov         rsi,qword ptr [&fnprocess]            <=== move the fnprocess pointer into register rsi
00007FF68DE89ADB  mov         ecx,18h  
00007FF68DE89AE0  rep movs    byte ptr [rdi],byte ptr [rsi]             <=== what is this moving. This is the line that overwrites memory
00007FF68DE89AE2  mov         dword ptr [rsp+28h],0  
00007FF68DE89AEA  lea         rax,[rsp+30h]                     
00007FF68DE89AEF  mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],rax               <=== fnprocess
00007FF68DE89AF4  mov         r9,qword ptr [rcv_pro]                <=== move rcv_pro pointer to register r9
00007FF68DE89AFC  mov         r8,qword ptr [address]                <=== move [address] pointer to register r9 
00007FF68DE89B04  mov         edx,dword ptr [port]                  <=== move port to register edx
00007FF68DE89B08  mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]
00007FF68DE89B0D  call        NEDSMsg::NEDSMsg (07FF68CD53F60h)
```

The comments are mine. The problem is that the "movs rep" line is overwriting memory - a local data member from a different class. I can tell that it is moving 18hex (24 decimal) bytes from one location to another, but what exactly is it moving? I assume that it is moving something related to the function pointer fnprocess, but what? And to where?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Update:
NEDSMsg is defined as

class NEDSMsg  : public Msg,
virtual public NEDSMsgGroup

The constructor for NEDSMsg is declared as
NEDSMsg(int port, const char * address = 0, L3Obj* rcv_pro = 0, fn_process fnprocess = 0);

Comment: You need to show more code from before. It's apparently copying the incoming `fnprocess` to outgoing argument for the `NEDSMsg` constructor. I assume its size is 24 bytes. Presumably `rsp` has been adjusted in previous code so `rsp+30h` should not overwrite wrong memory. It should be local stack space.

Comment: fnprocess is actually hard-coded as a nullptr. Being a pointer, wouldn't it be 64 bits? 8 bytes?

Comment: `[rsp+0x30]` could point to the first homing/shadow space if you take into account that after the prologue the stack is aligned and 8 bytes are occupied by the return address. Thus `[rsp+0x30]` could be the argument `fnprocess`. The fact that an object is copied there may imply that `fnprocess` has a default value passed by value (but not supplied by the caller). [Like in this example](https://godbolt.org/z/1EE4Yqzrc). The rest is just forwarding to the `NEDSMsg` ctor.

Comment: As I said, we need more code from before. Surely this isn't the start of the function. I expect there is a `sub rsp, xx` with `xx` being at least `0x48`. Which means the copying is to local stack memory and can not be overwriting other objects. The default argument for the `NEDSMsg` constructor is irrelevant since the `P2PRespMsg` is itself receiving the `fnprocess` which is passed on via the copy. The `=0` would apply only if the argument was not passed, but it is. Also you did not show the type `fn_process` so it may be some smart pointer object hence not size 8.

Answer (score 0):

Margaret Bloom's answer really helped, but I don't see how to mark that as the answer.

It turns out that this was a red herring. My overwrite was occurring somewhere else. I thought it was in this code because this code reused the memory used by another instance of the variable that was being overwritten.